# How to debug into service library from application

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-3.5, wcf-library

I created a service library and hosted it on an wcf service web site that is part of the same project. In the same project i have an app that consumes that wcf site via a web reference.

The wcf service web site is hosted on IIS and im using VS2008. First thing i noticed is that the svc i added to the wcf web service site is missing the code behind.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Sync_Local_CacheDBServiceLibrary.Inventario_CanalesService"%>
```

But how do i reference the code behind if its on another project. Or do i must change something on the web.config to allow for debugging into the service library?

Comment: I'd suspect you had two different processes (server and client). So you would need to debug both of them to see what is going on.
Also, how do you publish? Are you publishing a release version or a debug version to your IIS?

Comment: Im only building in debug.